# Ember JS error handling: Accessing errors in model not possible due to adapter error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, error-handling

The version of Ember is 2.10.2.

I asked a question about error responses and handling here: [Assertion Failed: `AdapterError` expects json-api formatted errors array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41872485/1156476)

I thought it was solved, but it is not. I can not get my errors to bind (is this a correct way to put it?) it to the model. I now have an adapter error saying:

```
message:"The adapter rejected the commit because it was invalid"
```

And the error response looks like this:

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "source": {
            "pointer": "\/data\/attributes\/email",
            "parameter": null
        },
        "detail": "user.email.not_blank"
    }]
}
```

Update: My submit function

```
user.save().then(
    () => {
        console.log('user saved');
    }, (adapterError) => {
        console.log(adapterError);
    }
);
```

Can someone please enlighten me on how to get to the error messages through the model?

Comment: if you are getting this error while saving model, try adding a error handler to it `model.save().then(successHandler, failureHandler)`

Comment: I believe I have. The question is updated with the user save function

Comment: Please check this  out http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_errors

Comment: Thank you very much. I can now print individual field errors. If you formulate it as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: When I console.log adapterError, I still get 'isAdapterError: true' with the error 'message:"The adapter rejected the commit because it was invalid"'. What does this mean?

Comment: I would appreciate if you could give an example. My problem is probably getting the correct response from the server or better getting the response normalized so that ember can handle it as expected. Maybe you can help me getting the data structure ember needs to handle these errors correctly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use extractErrors ?

> "extractErrors is used to extract model errors when a call to
>   DS.Model#save fails with an InvalidError. By default Ember Data
>   expects error information to be located on the errors property of the
>   payload object."

https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.JSONSerializer/methods/extractErrors?anchor=extractErrors